# 3d lattice path graphics

Tags: graphs-and-networks, lattices

I am trying to produce a figure of a 3d lattice path.

Currently, I am using

```
getedges[f_] := 
  Table[Style[UndirectedEdge[f[[i]], f[[i + 1]]], Thick, Black], {i, 
    1, Length@f - 1}];
getverts[f_] := 
 Table[Style[f[[i]], Black, FaceForm[White], 
   EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.008], Black}]], {i, 1, Length@f}]; With[{n = 
   3}, g = GridGraph[{n, n, n}];
 HighlightGraph[g, {PathGraph[#], getedges[#], getverts[#]}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"] & /@ FindPath[g, 1, n n n , {6}, All]]
```

which gives

[image]

However, I need something which

1) has edges aligned (so facing in one of three directions).
 2) is not on a slightly rotated/skewed lattice.
 3) potentially, has a labelled axes.

Is there an GraphLayout available for this, i.e. a standard 3D lattice?

Something like a 3D version of:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** It turns out `Graph3D` with `"HighDimensionalEmbedding"` layout does give the desired result:

```
Graph3D[GridGraph[{3,3,3}],  GraphLayout -> "HighDimensionalEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can create a 2D graph with the option `GraphLayout -> "HighDimensionalEmbedding"` and wrap the output with `Graph3D` to get a 3D layout:

```
g1 = GridGraph[{3, 3, 3}, GraphLayout -> "HighDimensionalEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
Graph3D @ g1
```

[image]

The same approach works with some `GraphLayout` settings:

```
SeedRandom[1]
g1 = GridGraph[{3, 3, 3}, GraphLayout -> "HighDimensionalEmbedding"];
g2 = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, GraphLayout -> "HighDimensionalEmbedding"];
g3 = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"];
g4 = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, GraphLayout -> "StarEmbedding"];
g5 = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"];

Grid[Transpose[{#, Graph3D@#} & /@ {g1, g2, g3, g4, g5}],  Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Note that 3D layout in the last example puts all vertices on a single plane.

**Original answer:**

You can use `Graph3D` with custom vertex coordinates:

```
g3d = With[{n = 3}, 
 Graph3D[GridGraph[{n, n, n}], 
  VertexCoordinates -> Tuples[Range[n], n]]]
```

[image]

```
Row[
 HighlightGraph[g3d, Subgraph[g3d, #],
    PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
    ImageSize -> Small] & /@ 
 FindPath[g3d, 1, 27, {6}, 5]]
```

[image]

To style vertices and edges on the selected paths:

```
Row[ 
  HighlightGraph[
    g3d, 
    {Style[#, Red], Style[EdgeList@Subgraph[g3d, #], Green]}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
    ImageSize -> Small] & /@ 
  FindPath[g3d, 1, 27, {6}, 5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you. I imagine its possible to edit the edge/vertex styles with HighlightGraph?

Comment: @AlexanderKartun-Giles, pls see the update.

Comment: Ok that is ideal. Thank you.